# How to Send a Raw Data Body to an Axios GETRequest in React Native?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I try to Get data from GET API But I did not want to fetch the all record only records match with the parameters that I send in raw data as json formate
How can I do this in react native Please help

```
const GetData = () => {
  axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/DonarsRecod',
      data: {
        organ: "Lungs"
      }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log("response", JSON.stringify(response.data))
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("error", error)
    })
}
```

Comment: send them in the url as query params: http://10.0.2.2:3000/DonarsRecod?organ=Lungs and handle that on your server side to reply with the correct data

Answer (score 0):

Instead `body` use `params` for GET HTTP method https://github.com/axios/axios#example

```
const GetData = () => {
  axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/DonarsRecod',
      params: {
        organ: "Lungs"
      }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log("response", JSON.stringify(response.data))
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("error", error)
    })
}
```